# Trouble running mbUnit 2 tests in SubSonic 2.1

Tags: testing, mbunit, subsonic2.2, runner

I'm still using Subsonic 2 for a few of my projects.  Wanting to hack it a little.
I've got the latest pull from the GIT repo, I'm using VS2008 Pro.

Looking in the SubSonic.Test project, the mbUnit dll referenced has a description of 'MbUnit.Framework 2.4.197', though the file version is '1.0.2700.29885'.
So I assume we're working with mbUnit 2.4.

I can compile the project fine, but I can't get Gallio to recognise the tests in 
SubSonic.Tests\bin\Debug\SubSonic.Tests.dll
It just comes up with 'no tests found'.

I have spent several hours trying to find docco on the net for this scenario, but there's not really any.  I'm also not keen on modifying the existing project as it gets further out of step with the GIT origin.
I have pasted the magic GUIDS into the test project file.

```
   <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

TestDriven.Net does this:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: SubSonic.Tests.dll ------

Gallio TestDriven.Net Runner - Version 3.1 build 397

Test Files:
 C:\data\Subsonic\2_x\SubSonic-2.1\SubSonic.Tests\bin\Debug\SubSonic.Tests.dll

Start time: 5:02 PM
Verifying test files.
Initializing the test runner.
Running the tests.
Disposing the test runner.
Stop time: 5:02 PM (Total execution time: 1.752 seconds)

Test Report: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/User/Local%20Settings/Temp/Gallio/TDNetRunner/Report/SubSonic.Tests.dll.html
** NO TESTS WERE RUN (No tests found) **
```

I can see this is using Gallio again; surely I don't need to uninstall Gallio ?!  I'm using it with mbUnit for my current projects, which work just fine.

Two years ago I had these unit test purring like a kitten, but I can't remember for the life of me how I was doing it.  It's now a version of VS later now and I would likely have lost the config in the upgrade.
I'm hoping to find someone out there who has the SubSonic v2.1 unit testing working and ask: *how are you running the tests ?*

Edit:
I contacted Rob Conery in the end and he confirmed (with some dismay) that TD .NET is no longer running the mbUnit 1 tests.  He thinks around td.net 1.3 was used when SubSonic 2 was in active development, but I can't find any historical downloads of that version.

That leaves resharper, which I haven't tested.

If I decide to upgrade the test framework to mbUnit 3, then I'll post it to GutHub.

Thanks Yann for comments - I've selected you as answerer.

UPDATE: Subsonic 2 Github sources were upgraded to mbUnit 3 around june 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SubSonic.Tests` is compiled against `MbUnit v1.0`. Gallio does not provide any support to such an old version of MbUnit. Please try replacing the MbUnit assembly (`Dependencies\MbUnit.Framework.dll`) by the latest compatible build. It should be v2.4.2. You will find it on the [**Gallio build server**](http://ccnet.gallio.org/Distributables/). Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the breaking changes between v1.0 and v2.4.

Comment: Btw, for new projects I recommend to use MbUnit v3.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider this, but there are a gazillion compile errors when using the mbUnit 2 compatibility dll. As said I really just want to run these test as-is, ie. without altering the project. There must be some way to run the mbUnit 1 tests - I was doing it before. Not with Gallio, clearly. I'm sure I got the details from some SubSonic post at the time, but trying to find the relevant info is like going through the proverbial haystack. Eric Kemp ? Are you there ?